# Flexbox items in flexbox item expanding parent

Tags: css, flexbox

I am having a problem while trying to use Flexbox for some markup. 
I have made this codepen to demonstrate my problem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjbzJY?editors=110

I want the image in the left(.item1 - The multicolor image) to dictate the width of the right box (.item2 - That contains alle the .itemitem$). 
But as it is now the right box gets wider and presses the left one.

Hope one of you can help me get to a solution! :)

The Code:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item1">
    <img src="http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    <div class="itemitem1 item">
      <div class="innerimg"><img src="http://hartcornstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/1280x900textPlaceholder-Image.gif" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="innertext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque non lorem ante. Curabitur fermentum ligula vel quam fermentum, eget suscipit mauris dictum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemitem2 item">
      <div class="innerimg"><img src="http://hartcornstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/1280x900textPlaceholder-Image.gif" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="innertext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque non lorem ante. Curabitur fermentum ligula vel quam fermentum, eget suscipit mauris dictum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemitem3 item">
      <div class="innerimg"><img src="http://hartcornstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/1280x900textPlaceholder-Image.gif" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="innertext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque non lorem ante. Curabitur fermentum ligula vel quam fermentum, eget suscipit mauris dictum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemitem4 item">
      <div class="innerimg"><img src="http://hartcornstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/1280x900textPlaceholder-Image.gif" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="innertext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque non lorem ante. Curabitur fermentum ligula vel quam fermentum, eget suscipit mauris dictum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemitem5 item">
      <div class="innerimg"><img src="http://hartcornstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/1280x900textPlaceholder-Image.gif" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="innertext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque non lorem ante. Curabitur fermentum ligula vel quam fermentum, eget suscipit mauris dictum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemitem6 item">
      <div class="innerimg"><img src="http://hartcornstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/1280x900textPlaceholder-Image.gif" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="innertext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque non lorem ante. Curabitur fermentum ligula vel quam fermentum, eget suscipit mauris dictum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemitem7 item">
      <div class="innerimg"><img src="http://hartcornstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/1280x900textPlaceholder-Image.gif" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="innertext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque non lorem ante. Curabitur fermentum ligula vel quam fermentum, eget suscipit mauris dictum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemitem8 item">
      <div class="innerimg"><img src="http://hartcornstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/1280x900textPlaceholder-Image.gif" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="innertext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque non lorem ante. Curabitur fermentum ligula vel quam fermentum, eget suscipit mauris dictum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemitem9 item">
      <div class="innerimg"><img src="http://hartcornstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/1280x900textPlaceholder-Image.gif" alt="" /></div>
      <div class="innertext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque non lorem ante. Curabitur fermentum ligula vel quam fermentum, eget suscipit mauris dictum.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

img {
  max-wifth: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  width: 930px;
  height: 180px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: gray;
}

.item1 {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item2 {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-align-content: space-between;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}

.item {
  width: 49%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  background: green;
}

.innerimg {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.innertext {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.innerimg img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It seems like flex-shrink: 0; on the box i dont want to shrink does the trick!

Answer (score -1):

It seems like flex-shrink: 0; on the box i don't want to shrink does the trick!